# What is happening when performing a logical AND between two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I had the example

```
a = np.arange(6)
```

What is happening between the following operation, and how is the output produced?

```
np.where(a > 4) and np.where(a > 2)
```

Comment: Is this someone else's code that you are trying to understand, or is it something that you are trying to do?   This Python `and` is not `np.logical_and`.  `np.where(np.logical_and(a<5, a>2))` makes some sense.  Combining `where` tuples with logical operators does not make sense.

Comment: I am trying to understand someone else's code.
If I recall correctly, they're using the result of this to modify another numpy array, such as x[...]

Comment: It doesn't make sense because there's no way that the first `where` will be *falsy*, so it always returns the second `where`.  In general use of `and` and `or` with numpy arrays is problematic.  They are best used for expressions that return a scalar True or False.

Comment: oh sorry I should have been more specific.
The code I created above is an example code, it was used to make a small example of a much larger code example that I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're confused that

```
np.where(a > 4) and np.where(a > 2)
```

returns the result of the 2nd expression

```
(array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

This is the expected behaviour when using `and`.

The evaluation works like this:

```
True and "hello"
```

first `True` is evaluated. As it is not *falsy*, next `"hello"` is returned.

This works perfectly for logical comparison, but has some non-intuitive behaviour when the expressions are not `True` or `False`

```
True and True # returns True (the 2nd `True`)
False and (lambda: "hello") # the first `False` evaluates to `False` and is returned, the lambda function is not evaluated
```

Similarly, for `or`, if the first expression is *truthy* then the second is not evaluated, but if the first is *falsy* then the 2nd is returned.

```
True or (print("False")) # first expression is True, the 2nd is not evaluated
False or (print("False")) # first expression is False, 2nd expression is evaluated, but nothing is returned as the 2nd expression returns nothing
(lambda:"hello") or False # returns the lambda function
False or (lambda:"hello") # also returns "hello"
False or True # first expression is false, therefore 2nd expression is returned.
```

The following things evaluate as *falsy*:

- `None`
- `False`
- `0`
- empty list, i.e, `[]` or `list()`
- empty dict, i.e. `{}` or `dict()`
- empty set, i.e. `set()`

Somewhat counter-intuitively, `np.nan` will evaluate as *truthy*

example:

```
np.nan or 100 # returns np.nan
np.nan and 100 # returns 100
```

while this may seem like a weird design choice, it leads to syntax like the following being possible:

```
# imagine that x is a list
# it it is not empty, return it
# do something more to x before returning it
if x:
  return x
x = ["goodbye", "cruel", "world", "its", "over", "walk", "on", "by"]
return x
```

Comment: As best I can tell that first `np.where` can never be *falsy*.

Answer (score 2):

This is less a Numpy question and more a Python question.

Python's `and` will return one of the operands — the left if it is false otherwise the right. For example:

`0 and 42` returns 0 because it's is false in this context. When both are True it will return the second:

`45 and 42` returns 42.

`np.where()` returns a tuple which will evaluate as True. The result is that:

```
np.where(a > 2) and np.where(a > 4)
```

Will always return the result of the second `np.where()`

Comment: This is complete news to me, I always thought any numbers that were non-zero were treated as True, hence I thought 45 and 42 would simply print True.